# Visual Studio 2022 doesn't want to link

Tags: c, linker, visual-studio-2022

I have problem using Visual Studio with a code which compiles perfectly using g++.

In practice, I have these 3 file (it's the minimum code which reproduce the problem...):

Source2.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
void test(double arg1, double arg2, int arg3);
```

Source.c

```
#include "Source2.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    test(10.1, 12.0, 13);

    return 0;
}
```

Source2.cpp

```
#include "Source2.h"
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/Eigenvalues"

using namespace Eigen;

void test(double arg1, double arg2, int arg3) {
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

I noticed that changing all extensions to .cpp instead of having .c/.cpp solves the problem, but I don't understand why it is needed while g++ works anyway...

Comment: Did Visual Studio use different compilers for the .c and the .cpp files? Why are you mixing them?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question in the edit? g++ compiles a file as c++

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited the question...Honestly I don't know if visual studio uses different compilers. In practice in my code I have files with simple C code while others where I use C++ functions and so they are saved using .cpp extension. I had no problems compiling in Ubuntu using a g++ command, is this because it doesn't care about the extension ?

Comment: g++ can compile any .c or .cpp files but they will be treated as C++ files only, while gcc can compile any .c or .cpp files but they will be treated as C and C++ respectively, and AFAIK the same goes for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

When you link .cpp and .c you need to add the followin in your .h file

```
#if __cplusplus 
extern "C" void test(double arg1, double arg2, int arg3);
#else
void test(double arg1, double arg2, int arg3);
#endif
```

Since C++ expects otherwise a mangled signature i.e. containing more information about parameters plus some other stuff.